# ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0 returning a bunch of errors when trying to build

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-library

I'm trying to change an Android app to use ActionBarSherlock. I added the library and set everything up (I think) correctly. But when I try to run the app I run into a bunch of errors, not with the app itself but with the ActionBarSherlock sources.

Here's what it's saying:

```
Information:Compilation completed with 24 errors and 13 warnings
Information:24 errors
Information:13 warnings
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\app\ActionBar.java
    Warning:Warning:line (949)[deprecation] FILL_PARENT in LayoutParams has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\app\ActionBarImpl.java
    Error:Error:line (66)error: ActionBarImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method setSecondaryProgress(int) in ActionBarSherlock
    Error:Error:line (135)error: constructor ActionBar in class ActionBar cannot be applied to given types;
required: Activity,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    Error:Error:line (147)error: constructor ActionBar in class ActionBar cannot be applied to given types;
required: Activity,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\widget\ActionBarContainer.java
    Warning:Warning:line (58)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\widget\ActionBarContextView.java
    Warning:Warning:line (81)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (115)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (129)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (231)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (244)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\widget\ScrollingTabContainerView.java
    Warning:Warning:line (280)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\widget\IcsProgressBar.java
    Warning:Warning:line (207)[deprecation] animationResolution in attr has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\view\menu\MenuPopupHelper.java
    Warning:Warning:line (145)[deprecation] removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(OnGlobalLayoutListener) in ViewTreeObserver has been deprecated
    Warning:Warning:line (216)[deprecation] removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(OnGlobalLayoutListener) in ViewTreeObserver has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\app\ActionBarWrapper.java
    Error:Error:line (16)error: ActionBarWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method startActionMode(Callback) in ActionBarSherlock
    Error:Error:line (24)error: constructor ActionBar in class ActionBar cannot be applied to given types;
required: Activity,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\view\ActionProviderWrapper.java
    Warning:Warning:line (22)[deprecation] onCreateActionView() in ActionProvider has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\src\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\view\menu\ListMenuItemView.java
    Warning:Warning:line (86)[deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in View has been deprecated
C:\Users\Nolan\IdeaProjects\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\test\com\actionbarsherlock\internal\ManifestParsingTest.java
    Error:Error:line (3)error: package org.junit does not exist
    Error:Error:line (5)error: cannot find symbol class ActionBarSherlockCompat
    Error:Error:line (5)error: static import only from classes and interfaces
    Error:Error:line (6)error: package org.hamcrest does not exist
    Error:Error:line (6)error: static import only from classes and interfaces
    Error:Error:line (7)error: package org.junit does not exist
    Error:Error:line (7)error: static import only from classes and interfaces
    Error:Error:line (10)error: cannot find symbol class Test
    Error:Error:line (17)error: cannot find symbol class Test
    Error:Error:line (24)error: cannot find symbol class Test
    Error:Error:line (31)error: cannot find symbol class Test
    Error:Error:line (13)error: cannot find symbol method cleanActivityName(String,String)
    Error:Error:line (14)error: cannot find symbol method equalTo(String)
    Error:Error:line (20)error: cannot find symbol method cleanActivityName(String,String)
    Error:Error:line (21)error: cannot find symbol method equalTo(String)
    Error:Error:line (27)error: cannot find symbol method cleanActivityName(String,String)
    Error:Error:line (28)error: cannot find symbol method equalTo(String)
    Error:Error:line (34)error: cannot find symbol method cleanActivityName(String,String)
    Error:Error:line (35)error: cannot find symbol method equalTo(String)
```

I'm really not sure what's going wrong, since it doesn't seem to be anything that I did but rather a problem with ActionBarSherlock itself. What should I do?

Also I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to create and build the project. And the project itself is a library project with two different versions so I can support a free and paid version of the app.

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me what version of Android you are compiling in your project?

Comment: Target is API 16, Minimum is API 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Did you add the ActionbBarSherlock in your project correcly?
[image: see Librairy]

2) Is your project buid target >= Android 3.0 ?
[image: see Project Build Target]

3) Are you using the android support librairy in your project? If so please remove it because it is already in the ActionBarSherlock librairy

[image: See Java Build Path]

4) Each time you try to include the ActionBarSherlock into your project be sure to do steps 1,2,3 and clean those projects frequently if you see any "x" and "!" marks on both projects
[image: Project -> Clean...]

Comment: Whoops, I had the support library as part of my project and it was causing all the errors. Fixed, thanks.